# Getting measurements of UI elements in React Native

Tags: react-native

Is there a way to get pixel measurements of native elements in React Native? For example:

[image]

Right now I'm hardcoding how much padding needs to exist so that the content isn't covered by the nav bar:

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    paddingTop: 64
  }
});
```

IMO this is not acceptable. Is there some way to measure these elements?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use the [onLayout](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/view.html#onlayout) event:

```
getInitialState() {
  return { }
}

<View onLayout={(event) => this.measureView(event)}>

measureView(event) {
  console.log('event properties: ', event);
  this.setState({
        x: event.nativeEvent.layout.x,
        y: event.nativeEvent.layout.y,
        width: event.nativeEvent.layout.width,
        height: event.nativeEvent.layout.height
  })
}
```

As far as calling these on Native elements, I have not tried, but possibly passing the function into the component may do it, or wrapping the native element in a view and calling the function on the outer view.